# In Apache Kafka, how can I have conditional message publication in order to support Optimistic Concurrency

Tags: java, apache-kafka, event-sourcing, optimistic-concurrency, eventstoredb

I want to use Apache Kafka to power an event-sourced persistence.

I know that other event-based persistence support Optimistic Concurrency, such as described [in Event Store documentation](https://eventstore.org/docs/dotnet-api/3.0.1/optimistic-concurrency-and-idempotence/), however, [the following - still unresolved, low-priority - ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-2260) seems to indicate it is not a possibility at this time.

Anyone with an idea ?

Comment: That ticket has **low** priority so...

Comment: This is currently not possible. Read this article by my colleague Jesper: https://medium.com/serialized-io/apache-kafka-is-not-for-event-sourcing-81735c3cf5c

Comment: Very interesting read. May I asked what is used as the underlying database in serialized.io ? is  it proprietary, or built on top of an existing storage product?